# Momentum and Angular momentum with sympy

Tags: python, sympy

How do I calculate the momentum and angular momentum a force causes on an object (in a vacuum) using python/sympy

I'm looking for a library to do this, I'm not stuck to sympy, but an answer with sympy will be fine (To not make the question too broad).

What have I tried? Well, I tried reading the documentation for sympy and realized it is not directed at programmers, but physics students.

Answer (score 1):

Forces and torques cause ***changes*** in momentum and angular momentum of a body. For these calculations physics is unavoidable and there is no general solution because unless we know details about the system (what kind of force or torque is acting, what is the shape and mass of the system etc.) under consideration we cannot calculate the changes in momentum.

[image]

So if we know how force `F` varies with time we can calculate the x, y and z components of changes in angular momentum by integrating the corresponding components of force with time. SymPy can help us to do the integration. Although, SymPy has a dedicated Physics Vector module, we don't even need it if we have a simple enough force equation for which just [Sympy's integrate](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html) function is sufficient. For example, let's say that the only non-zero component of the force acting on the system is the x-component given as `cos(t)`.

```
import sympy as sp
t,t0,t1 = sp.symbols('t,t0,t1')

Fx = sp.cos(t) # x-component of Force
MomX = sp.integrate( Fx, (t,t0,t1) ) # x-component of change in momentum
# MomX = sin(t1) - sin(t0)
```

Similar discussion holds for change in angular momentum except that force will be replaced by a torque or if one has enough details about the geometry of the system one may be able to calculate the torque from the force itself and then integrate it with respect to time to get the change in angular momentum.